# Add value from another table to my resultset (e.g. find username for user_id)

Tags: sql, sqlite

Some friends dragged me into writing an IRC bot that helps monitoring the consumption of fluids throughout the day. Every user in our channel can submit an amount in liters every time he/she drank something and that value will be stored in a drinks_today table which is reset at the end of the day. The bot uses SQLite for data storage.

I am stuck with an SQL-only way to find out the top 3 drinkers of the day.

I have the following database tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users(user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, active_days INTEGER DEFAULT 0, drinks_total FLOAT DEFAULT 0); 
CREATE TABLE drinks_today(user_id INTEGER, amount FLOAT, timestamp INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id));
```

I can find the top 3 user_ids as follows:

```
SELECT user_id,drinks_sum FROM ( SELECT SUM(amount) AS drinks_sum,user_id FROM drinks_today GROUP BY user_id ) ORDER BY drinks_sum DESC LIMIT 3;
```

The result will be:

```
1|9.0
4|8.5
3|6.0
```

Now I am looking for a way to (correctly) map the username into the result set. I tried the following statement, but the result was not correct:

```
SELECT u.name,drinks_sum FROM ( SELECT SUM(d.amount) AS drinks_sum FROM drinks_today d GROUP BY d.user_id) JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id=user_id ORDER BY drinks_sum DESC LIMIT 3;
```

The result set will contain the first three users of users table and each will be equipped with the one top score. Which is, of course, completely wrong.

How can I get the username into my result set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

think you can do this all in one.

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name, SUM(d.amount) as drunk
FROM users u
INNER JOIN drinks_today dt ON dt.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.name
ORDER by drunk DESC -- or maybe ORDER BY SUM(d.amount) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

**Edit**

Enjoy responsibly.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi Raphaël!

This takes the cake!

I just edited a little bit as follows:

    SELECT u.name, SUM(dt.amount) as drunk 
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN drinks_today dt ON dt.user_id = u.user_id
    GROUP BY u.user_id, u.name
    ORDER BY drunk DESC LIMIT 3;